# Display number of months or round up for duration of membership in election stats

Tags: feature-request, election

I know the election stats have just been overhauled (can't find the post), but I find it a bit misleading to say I've only been a member for a year, when I've been there for almost 2 years (1 year 10 months). I think it makes me seem like a less attractive candidate than I would be if they knew I'd been there nearly 2 years.

Can you either:

(1) Display the number of months as well

or

(2) Round up to the next year?

[image] vs [image]

Comment: On the other hand, gathering 4 k reputation in one year is more impressive than gathering it in two years.

Comment: There's not even a hover title? Inconsistency!